# Appending results from a list to a string

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, boolean

Heavy python beginner here. I want to create a simple function for a PIN guessing game that receives two 4-digit lists ( [guess], [answer] ) and returns a string with 4 letters stating how close I am to guessing the correct [answer] sequence (eg. Higher, True, Lower, Higher)
However, I get a new list for each string:

```
def checkNumbers(guess,right):
    for n in range(4):
        result = []
        if guess[n] == right[n]:
          result.append("T")        #true
        elif guess[n] < right[n]:
            result.append("H")     #higher
        elif guess[n] > right[n]:
            result.append("L")     #lower
        else:
          result.append("F")     #false
        print (result)
    return

checkNumbers([1,2,3,5],[2,2,1,6])
```

The result should look like this:

```
checkNumbers([1,2,3,4], [2, 2, 1 , 6]) #call function with ([guess], [answer])

'HTLH' #returns a string stating how accurate [guess] is to [answer] list
```

Result looks like this however:

```
checkNumbers([1,2,3,5],[2,2,1,6])

['H']
['T']
['L']
['H']
```

Thanks very much in advance for any help I could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use string instead of list or ["".join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
def checkNumbers(guess, right):
    result = ""
    for n in range(4):
        if guess[n] == right[n]:
            result += "T"   # true
        elif guess[n] < right[n]:
            result += "H"   # higher
        elif guess[n] > right[n]:
            result += "L"   # lower
        else:
            result += "F"   # false
    print(result)
```

but... maybe you want to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
def checkNumbers(guess, right):
    result = ""
    for g, r in zip(guess, right):
        if g == r:
            result += "T"   # true
        elif g < r:
            result += "H"   # higher
        elif g > r:
            result += "L"   # lower
        else:
            result += "F"   # false
    print(result)
```

Funny bonus here:

```
def checkNumbers(guess, right):
    print("".join("THL"[(g > r) + (g != r)] for g, r in zip(guess, right)))
```

I don't get why you need `else` part...

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the list and print the result *outside* of the loop:

```
def checkNumbers(guess, right):
    result = []
    for n in range(4):
        # do loopy stuff
    print (result)
    return  # not strictly necessary
```

If you do it inside, you are creating a new list on every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I find myself occasionally doing this in my functions lol.
I want to iterate the result in a string format, but I think it's the way I defined my variable
```result = []```.
How can I get it to give me ```"HYLY"``` rather than ```["H"]["T"]["L"]["H"]``` ?